# Why does this Scala implicit conversion fail when explicit conversion works?

Tags: scala

Why doesn't the following implicit conversion work even though explicitly calling the function works?

```
scala> implicit def view[A, C](xs: C)(implicit ev: C <:< Iterable[A]) = new { def bar = 0 } 
view: [A, C](xs: C)(implicit ev: <:<[C,scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[A]])java.lang.Object{def bar: Int}

scala> List(1) bar
<console>:147: error: Cannot prove that List[Int] <:< scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[A].
              List(1) bar
                  ^

scala> view(List(1)) bar
res37: Int = 0
```

Comment: I put your code into the scala eclipse IDE and it failed it on three counts - value view is not a member of AnyRef(def bar: Int) Note: implicit view not applicable here; identifier expected but '[' found; not found: type error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really answering your question (i.e., I'm answering to "how do I make this work" but not to the "why does it not work");  anyway hopefully this will help someone else make some progress towards an answer.

So... In the first case, the compiler can't infer correctly that A is an Int, given that C is a List[Int]. Honestly I'm more surprised that passing the List explicitly actually works, since the relationship between A and C is so indirect (you have a A and a C, since C is a subtype of Iterable[A] and since C is a List[Int], then A must be an Int; not a very straightforward inference...).

You can make it work by being more explicit about the relationship between C and A, like this:

```
scala> implicit def view[A, C[A]](xs: C[A])(implicit ev: C[A] <:< Iterable[A]) = 
       new { def bar = 0 }
view: [A, C[A]](xs: C[A])(implicit ev: <:<[C[A],Iterable[A]])java.lang.Object{def bar: Int}

scala> List(1) bar
res0: Int = 0
```

or (given that you're not using A):

```
scala> implicit def view[C](xs: C)(implicit ev: C <:< Iterable[_]) = 
       new { def bar = 0 }

scala> List(1) bar
res1: Int = 0
```

Comment: However, this constrains xs's type to be an applied unary type constructor; all other types are excluded. See an explanation here at http://suereth.blogspot.com/2011/06/generic-quicksort-in-scala.html.

Comment: whoa, that's some black-belt level type-fu there! I see that my "solution" is actually breaking the carefully constructed type signature of your method, but I will need some time to ingest the rest of the post you've sent... However, FWIW, my second definition of view still works with non-unary type constructors. I've tested it with `class Foo(t: List[Int]) extends Iterable[Int] {def iterator : Iterator[Int] = t.iterator }`, that has no type parameters, and `(new Foo(List(1))).view bar` works.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, as the error message suggests, it cannot infer `A`. There's no information the compiler can use to infer what `A` must be, so it must assume it can be anything.

You might retort that it can infer `A` from `C <:< Iterable[A]`, but that would turn the problem on its head: instead of using `<:<` to check constraints, it would use the constraints to infer the type of `A`! That logic is not sound.

Comment: But with most unification-like provers, information has to flow in both directions and are resolved in the middle. Consider the explicit call, which does work and infers `A`.