# Scala implicit conversion of container nested types

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, functor, implicit, scala-compiler

Consider the following example:

```
case class A()

case class B()

object Conversions {
  implicit def aToB(a: A): B = B()

  implicit def convert[U, T](seq: Seq[U])(implicit converter: U => T): Seq[T] = {
    seq.map(converter)
  }
}

object Main {
  import Conversions._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sa = Seq(A())

    def example(): Seq[B] = sa
  }
}
```

This example won't compile by scala compiler for version 2.11.8. I do compilation with IntelliJ Idea, but actually idea don't produce error on the fly and shows that implicit is used for conversion:
[Screenshot from Intellij Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7f3t.png)

To workaround this issue I've used the approach described here:
["Scala: Making implicit conversion A->B work for Option[A] -> Option[B]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823816/scala-making-implicit-conversion-a-b-work-for-optiona-optionb)

My code started to look as follow:

```
case class A()

case class B()

object Conversions {
  implicit def aToB(a: A): B = B()

  trait ContainerFunctor[Container[_]] {
    def map[A, B](container: Container[A], f: A => B): Container[B]
  }

  implicit object SeqFunctor extends ContainerFunctor[Seq] {
    override def map[A, B](container: Seq[A], f: (A) => B): Seq[B] = {
      Option(container).map(_.map(f)).getOrElse(Seq.empty[B])
    }
  }

  implicit def functorConvert[F[_], A, B](x: F[A])(implicit f: A => B, functor: ContainerFunctor[F]): F[B] = functor.map(x, f)
}

object Main {

  import Conversions._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sa = Seq(A())

    def example(): Seq[B] = sa
  }
}
```

This code compiles well and works as needed.

My questions are:
Why the first approach fails to compile?
Is this somehow related to type erasure and if yes, how usage of Functor helps with it?
How compiler resolves implicits for both of this cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the first approach fails to compile?

[I've opened a bug for this issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10405).

This seems like a compiler quirk in implicit search. Since you're providing the `convert` method which converts `Seq[A] => Seq[B]`, the compiler isn't able to properly align the types. This is the output of compiling with `Ytyper-debug`:

```
|    [search #3] start `[U, T](seq: Seq[U])(implicit converter: U => T)Seq[T]` inferring type T, searching for adaptation to pt=A => T (silent: method example in Test) implicits disabled
|    [search #3] considering aToB
|    |-- { ((a: A) => Conversions.aToB(a)) } : pt=A => ? EXPRmode (silent: method example in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |-- ((a: A) => Conversions.aToB(a)) : pt=A => ? EXPRmode (silent: method example in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |-- Conversions.aToB(a) EXPRmode (silent: value $anonfun in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    |-- Conversions.aToB BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: value $anonfun in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    |    \-> (a: A)B
|    |    |    |    |-- a : pt=A BYVALmode-EXPRmode (silent: value $anonfun in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    |    \-> A
|    |    |    |    \-> B
|    |    |    \-> A => B
|    |    \-> A => B
|    [adapt] aToB adapted to { ((a: A) => Conversions.aToB(a)) } based on pt A => T
|    [search #3] solve tvars=?T, tvars.constr= >: B
|    solving for (T: ?T)
|    [search #3] success inferred value of type A => =?B is SearchResult({
|      ((a: A) => Conversions.aToB(a))
|    }, TreeTypeSubstituter(List(type T),List(B)))
|    solving for (A: ?A)
|    solving for (A: ?A)
|    solving for (A: ?A)
|    solving for (A: ?A)
|    [search #3] considering $conforms
|    solving for (A: ?A)
|    [adapt] $conforms adapted to [A]=> <:<[A,A] based on pt A => T
|    [search #3] solve tvars=?T, tvars.constr= >: A
|    solving for (T: ?T)
|    [search #3] success inferred value of type A => =?A is SearchResult(scala.Predef.$conforms[A], TreeTypeSubstituter(List(type T),List(A)))
```

It seems like the search #3 is trying to adapt `conforms` (`<:<`) which takes the entire implicit search from `A => B` to `A => A`. If I compile with the `-Yno-predef`, the implicit conversion succeeds:

```
|    |    |-- [U, T](seq: Seq[U])(implicit converter: U => T)Seq[T] : pt=Seq[B] EXPRmode (silent: method example in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    [search #4] start `[U, T](seq: Seq[U])(implicit converter: U => T)Seq[T]`, searching for adaptation to pt=A => B (silent: method example in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    [search #4] considering aToB
|    |    |    |-- { ((a: A) => Conversions.aToB(a)) } : pt=A => B EXPRmode (silent: method example in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    |-- ((a: A) => Conversions.aToB(a)) : pt=A => B EXPRmode (silent: method example in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    |    |-- Conversions.aToB(a) : pt=B EXPRmode (silent: value $anonfun in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Conversions.aToB BYVALmode-EXPRmode-FUNmode-POLYmode (silent: value $anonfun in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \-> (a: A)B
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- a : pt=A BYVALmode-EXPRmode (silent: value $anonfun in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \-> A
|    |    |    |    |    |    \-> B
|    |    |    |    |    \-> A => B
|    |    |    |    \-> A => B
|    |    |    [adapt] aToB adapted to { ((a: A) => Conversions.aToB(a)) } based on pt A => B
|    |    |    [search #4] success inferred value of type A => B is SearchResult({
|    |    |      ((a: A) => Conversions.aToB(a))
|    |    |    }, )
|    |    |    |-- [U, T](seq: Seq[U])(implicit converter: U => T)Seq[T] : pt=Seq[B] EXPRmode (silent: method example in Test) implicits disabled
|    |    |    |    \-> Seq[B]
|    |    |    [adapt] [U, T](seq: Seq[U])(implicit converter: U => T)Seq[T] adapted to [U, T](seq: Seq[U])(implicit converter: U => T)Seq[T] based on pt Seq[B]
|    |    |    \-> Seq[B]
|    |    [adapt] Seq[A] adapted to [U, T](seq: Seq[U])(implicit converter: U => T)Seq[T] based on pt Seq[B]
|    |    \-> Seq[B]
|    \-> [def example] ()Seq[B]
```

> Is this somehow related to type erasure and if yes, how usage of
>   Functor helps with it?

The second example works because you're now laying out explicitly how to map a `Seq[A]` into a `Seq[B]` by using the `Functor` type class and thus when the compiler sees a `Seq[A]`, it has an implicit to convert it to `Seq[B]`:

```
def example(): Seq[B] = Conversions.functorConvert[Seq, A, B](sa)({
        ((a: A) => Conversions.aToB(a))
}, Conversions.SeqFunctor);
```

Note you require both a conversion from `A => B`, and a `Functor[Seq]` to be able to map over all `A`s to convert them to `B`s, which is what it does using `conversions.aToB`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Perfect explanation.

Comment: @andrii.ilin My explanation is actually flawed, since I missed the `convert` method which converts `Seq[A] => Seq[B]` in your first example. Digging into it now.

Comment: I thought that your first explanation covers that. Still thanks for an explanation.

Comment: @andrii.ilin See my new explanation. I think this is a bug. Compiling with `Yno-predef` actually makes this work.

Comment: Awesome, but hard to understand compiler debug output, haven't worked with it yet. Have voted for bug. Waiting for the explanation from scala guys. Seems like Intellij Idea compiler that used for detecting compiler errors on the fly uses Yno-predef  or has another implementation for implicit search. Thanks again for you investigation and explanation.

Comment: @andrii.ilin It has the same implicit search, I've just used special flags to view the process of searching for implicits. Basically, for some reason the compiler tries to convert `A => B` to `A => A` with `Predef.conforms`, which leaves no change for `convert` to be found as a suitable implicit. I will update this answer once the folks update the issue.

Comment: After spending some time it seems that `$conforms` have resolved everything correctly but result of resolution have been applied to wrong argument. `[search #3] success inferred value of type A => =?B is SearchResult({
|      ((a: A) => Conversions.aToB(a))
|    }, TreeTypeSubstituter(List(type T),List(B)))` after this line we trying to prove that T is A after proving this we can see that `TreeTypeSubstituter(List(type T),List(A))` instead of  `TreeTypeSubstituter(List(A),List(B))` if I get everything right.

Comment: @andrii The problem is that `conforms` isn't the right implicit conversion. We get an `A => A` conversion instead of `A => B`>